# zabbix user defined macro in script parameters (media type)

Tags: scripting, zabbix

I have an alert script in zabbix 3.4 that I would like to be run using user defined macros `{$FOO}`, basically the macro would store a predefined value

I am setting the `{$FOO}` in the media type (see screenshot) and using the predefault macro `{ALERT.MESSAGE}`

[image: Media type configuration with macros]

The `{ALERT.MESSAGE}` macro works fine, but the `{$FOO}` is not resolved on the script. I have configured `{$FOO}` as a global macro or template macro and host macro but nothing seems to work.

Question: Is is possible to use user macros on media type? Something wrong in my logic?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use usermacros directly in alertscript parameters, only a small subset of macros are supported there.

Instead, try including your usermacro in the alert message, it should be resolved there.